# Angular select with ngModel gives me [$rootScope:inprog] error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not very good with angular, but i know some basics. Now, I have access points and want to assign them to a building. I can select this building with a `<select>`. I have written a simple controller, but it wont work. What am I making wrong, i cant find a solution.

**Edit 1:**
I can see the option fields (they are 3). But after I select one of these, my browser console throws the exception

**Edit 2:** Plunkr -> https://plnkr.co/edit/EIPs8yVlTSaYQ0EuZLTb (i hope, this url works) .. When you click on "Neuer Access-Point" the error will occur, after you select something on "Gebäude"

Select field

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.input.building">
    <option ng-repeat="building in $ctrl.buildings" ng-value="building.id" ng-bind="building.name"></option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
(function () {

    function createController(Building) {
        var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.buildings = null;

        ctrl.input = {
            host: '',
            desc: '',
            web: '',
            building: ''
        };

        ctrl.$onInit = function () {
            Building.getAll().then(function (res) {
                if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
                    ctrl.buildings = res.data;
                }
            });
        };
    }

    angular.module('app').controller('CreateController', createController)

})();
```

Error

```
angular.js:14791 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at angular.js:88
at p (angular.js:18897)
at m.$digest (angular.js:18319)
at m.$apply (angular.js:18640)
at Object.$$debounceViewValueCommit (angular.js:29394)
at Object.$setViewValue (angular.js:29372)
at angular.js:33596
at m.$eval (angular.js:18533)
at m.$apply (angular.js:18632)
at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:33595)
```

Comment: I am playing with your code for a while, but I can't reproduce your error with this information.

Could you create some jsfiddle with the same issue?

Comment: Did you check the error link angular gives you? That's often very helpful.

Comment: Yes, I tried some solutions, but without success. I have added plunkr to post (edit 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the issue with your code.

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-app="accessPoints" ng-controller="RootController **as $root**">
```

Change it to simply

```
ng-controller="RootController as anythingButNot$root"
```

or even just `ng-controller="RootController"`

Declaring any controller as `$root` is creating mess for you. `$root` is the root level controller of your application. Inside your `html` if you declare any `controller as $root`, it tries to overwrite `$root`, creating trouble with digest cycle, hence you are getting the error.

Link to updated plunk => https://plnkr.co/edit/UcJHVmekMqWMXJBnv2Cu?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I tried to fix it for days. You really saved me.